# HTML data to a specific excel spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have an HTML code that will open a new excel spread sheet. I would like for it to open a specific spreadsheet and keep adding data to it. Here is the code:

```
<script>
function ToExcel(){ 
if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
var xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
var xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(); 
var table=document.getElementById('inner_table')

//var tableCells=document.getElementById('inner_table').cells
var tableRows=document.getElementById('inner_table').rows
xlBook.worksheets("Sheet1").activate; 
var XlSheet = xlBook.activeSheet; 
xlApp.visible = true; 
var xlRow = 1;
var xlCol = 1;
var R=0;
while(tableRows[R] != null)
{
var tableCells =tableRows[R].cells
var C = 0; 
xlCol=1;
while(tableCells[C] != null)
{
XlSheet.cells(xlRow, xlCol).value = tableCells[C].childNodes[1].value;
xlCol++;
C++;
}
xlRow++;
R++;
} 
XlSheet.rows.autofit; 
XlSheet.columns.autofit; 
} 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with your code? What is your SPECIFIC question?

Comment: You want it to open a spreadsheet on your computer and add data to it before your eyes?  The document cannot be open while it is being accessed by another program (such as yours).

Comment: I am using the code above to create a form in which a patient can fill in data such as name and date of birth, etc. I have a specific log sheet in excel designed to store this information from the form. The code will open a new spreadsheet every time and I would like it to open my specific log sheet and store the information on the next available line. Then, on the next form, I would like to open the same log sheet and send the next set of information to the next available line. Is this possible?